# How to attach event to the newly added anchor using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

*I trying to attach a click event for the newly added anchor tag(.he) after the #foo anchor tag. But the click event is not happening. I have used (.on). Can you guys help me in this ?**

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>Attaching event</title>
       <style>p { background:yellow; margin:6px 0; }</style>
       <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        </head>
    <body>
    <p>Hello</p>
    how are
    <p>you?</p>

    <button>Call remove() on paragraphs</button>

    <a id="foo" href="#" style="display:block">Testing the bind and unbind</a>


    <script>
        $("button").on('click',function () {

            $("#foo").after("<a class='he' href='#'>asdfasdf</a>");

        });
        $(".he").on('click', function(){
                alert("test");
        });     

    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to delegate to a static parent element like this

```
$(document).on('click','.he',function(){

//code here
});
```

Comment: So for each and every new element added, do i need to specify the selector name every time, i feel this is a optional parameter. the click event will automatically attached to the newly added element.

Comment: Using this code will add a function to any newly added element with the class .he

Answer (score 0):

Use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)

```
$("body").on("click", ".he", function() {
    alert("test");
});
```

Instead of `body` you can use any static parent element of `.he`.

Answer (score 0):

use `.live`. and don't forget to add your code inner jquery clousure

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("button").on('click',function () {
            $("#foo").after("<a class='he' href='#'>asdfasdf</a>");
        });

        $(".he").live('click', function(){
            alert("test");
        });
    });
<script>
```

Comment: Live is deprecated since 1.7 and removed in versions later than 1.9

Comment: I'm sorry. I do not know if babu use jquery 1.9, because he doesn't mention it in his question.

Comment: maybe the problem is because the code is should placed inner jquery clousure.

Comment: I use  * jQuery JavaScript Library v1.9.1

Answer (score 0):

you will have to put the below code inside $("button").click block.

```
  $(".he").on('click', function(){
                    alert("test");
            });
```

Link for jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wbWLE/

Comment: Can i know why the element when placed outside the $("button").click won't work.

Comment: When the element is created then you need to attach the event. Hope its working.

Answer (score 0):

You can instead bind the click event to the anchor before appending it to the DOM like this:

```
 var $he = $("<a class='he' href='#'>asdfasdf</a>").on('click', function(){
                 alert("test");
            })
 $("#foo").after($he);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either attach a handler to the anchor directly before it is appended into the document:

```
$("button").on('click',function () {
   $("<a class='he' href='#'>asdfasdf</a>")
      .on('click', function(){
         alert("test");
      })
      .insertAfter("#foo");
});
```

or bind a delegate handler on the document that will catch all clicks on anchors with `he` as their class:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.he', function() {
   alert("test");
});
$("button").on('click',function () {
   $("<a class='he' href='#'>asdfasdf</a>").insertAfter("#foo");
});
```